# Visual Studio 2010 removes Value="" on saving

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This is a very strange situation its never happened to me before, I have googled but without result.

Basically on my page within my solution i have multiple drop down boxes the first on each is

```
 <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please select..."></asp:ListItem>
```

When I press Ctrl S or click the floopy disk icon VS automatically removes Value="" so the result is

```
 <asp:ListItem Text="Please select..."></asp:ListItem>
```

I'm just wondering if any one else around the globe has experienced this? if so how did you fix it! because its really starting to irritate me :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with this being a standard thing. Could you list any Extensions you have installed?

Comment: Try this: `<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Please select..." Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>`